# Reading data from a txt. file into an array and then summing the rows and columns

Tags: c++, arrays

Update: I need help figuring out how to print this correctly. I've tried and I can not get it right. What would you do?

I am using c++. My assignment is to read in data from a .txt file into a 10 by 10 array. Then I am supposed to add each row and put their total on the end. Then each column needs added and the totals in a new row at the bottom. I also need the sums summed in the corner. Here is an example of what the output has to look like: [Example of output screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPCM0.png)

[image]

Here is the code I currently have:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Kaitlin Stevers" << endl;
    cout << "Exercise 9A - Arrays" << endl;
    cout << "October 31, 2016" <<endl;

    const int ROWS = 10;
    const int COLS = 10;
    float numbers[11][11];

    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("Ex9data.txt");


    for(int countRows = 0; countRows < ROWS; countRows++)
    {
        for(int countColumns = 0; countColumns < COLS; countColumns++)
        {
            inputFile >> numbers[countRows][countColumns];
        }
    }

    inputFile.close();

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
        column = 0;
        numbers[10][i]=0
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            numbers[10][i] +=numbers[j][i];
        }
        //do the printing here & storing... column based sum here.
    }
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        row = 0;
        numbers[i][10]=0;
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
        numbers[i][10] +=numbers[i][i];
        }
        //do the printing here & storing... row based sum here.
     }
     return 0;   
}
```

I need to know how to print the whole array.

Comment: _"The book I go by has examples of how to do it "_ What do you think makes the difference if the data was read from a file or from the console?

Comment: You did it and read the file, so you have the data in an array in memory now, and your work isn't related to the .txt file anymore. You should focus now on iterating over the elements of the array and perform the needed calculations.

Comment: I don't have a clue what I'm doing... Guys.. Like maybe an example would help.

Comment: You should change `numbers` to `float numbers[ROWS][COLS];`.

Comment: You mean change float numbers[10][10] to float numbers[ROWS][COLS]

Comment: What I would do is allocate an extra row and column and use that space to store the sum. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/OioK4zqLh1ly7e5T

Comment: I noticed you did a vector not an array. There is a difference isn't there?? I know mine needs to be an array.

Comment: How to hack stack community: just tell them you are a woman and they will do your homework for you ;)

Comment: Hahahaha! That's to funny! :p

Comment: Replace it with `float data[ROWS+1][COLUMNS+1]`

Comment: What does that do? Thanks for the help everyone. You all are awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Logman ;P" << endl;
    cout << "Exercise 9A - Arrays" << endl;
    cout << "October 31, 2016" <<endl;

    int ROWS = 0;
    int COLS = 0;

    float numbers[11][11];


    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("Ex9data.txt");

    inputFile >> ROWS;
    inputFile >> COLS;

    for(int countRows = 0; countRows < ROWS; countRows++)
    {
        for(int countColumns = 0; countColumns < COLS; countColumns++)
        {
            inputFile >> numbers[countRows][countColumns];
        }
    }

    inputFile.close();

    for(int i=0;i<COLS;i++)
    {
        numbers[ROWS][i] = 0.0f;
        for(int j=0;j<ROWS;j++)
        {
            numbers[ROWS][i] +=numbers[j][i];
        }

    }

    for(int i=0;i<ROWS+1;i++)
    {
        numbers[i][COLS] = 0.0f;
        for(int j=0;j<COLS;j++)
        {
            numbers[i][COLS] +=numbers[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<ROWS+1;i++)
    {
        if(i==ROWS) 
        {
            for(int j=0;j<(COLS+1)*10;j++) cout << "-";
            cout <<endl;
        }
        for(int j=0;j<COLS+1;j++)
        {
            if(j==COLS) cout << "|";
            cout << setw(9) << setprecision(6) <<  numbers[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout <<endl;
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: /Users/kaitlinstevers/Desktop/Screen Shot 2016-11-03 at 9.21.24 PM.png   The output... Is all zeros.. something isn't working. Did it run right for you? I also forgot to set it to only 1 decimal place.

Comment: Post your input file (Ex9data.txt).

Comment: @KatieStevers check if your Ex9data.txt file look similar to my [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/viewproject.php?URL=compile_cpp11_online.php&PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMSTctSHpRZTdyaDg)

Comment: 2-D array of data: first entry is num of rows, second entry is num of columns, 
remaining entries are the data values listed by rows
3
5
1.0
2.5
3.0
4.5
5.0
2
2.5
3
4.5
5
3
3
4
3
4

Comment: the comment above has my file. I put that in on the thing you sent me and then tried to run the code. It said permission denied.. lol

Comment: I updated code check it [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/viewproject.php?URL=compile_cpp11_online.php&PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMMXhUa1p0Ym52OUU) first click compile then after a while execute. But this code has limitation to maximum 10 number of rows or columns. If you want to remove this limit tell me.

Comment: can you tell me what 0.0f does in the line of code  "numbers[ROWS][i] = 0.0f;"

Comment: @KatieStevers in c++ you have multiple build in data types. For floating point precision numbers like 3.567 you can use float or double. And in your app you used float as numbers type. To prevent casting from one data type to another you can specify that number (in this case 0.0) is type float (default double) and to do that you need to add "f" at the end of number.

Answer (score 1):

Since the data is read and put into the matrix, now iterate the matrix and do the column based sum. Sample code for it is below.

```
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
    sum = 0;
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
       {
         sum+= numbers[j][i];
       }
//do the printing here or storing... basically you get the column based sum here.
    }
```

for Row based sum

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
        sum = 0;
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
           {
             sum+= numbers[i][j];
           }
    //do the printing here or storing... basically you get the row based sum here.
        }
```

Comment: Can I  just store it to another variable? Then print with that variable? Should I store it as a string or float? Sorry for all the questions. This is the second biggest and most complex project we have done.

Comment: the value of the sum will get refreshed with each iteration, so I would make a new array to store the values; and if you want to be fancy, you can create a new row/column and store the row based /column based sum for the respective row there.

Comment: Hahaha, okay I want to do the new row column. So do I change the size of the array to 11 by 11 and then lol i'll have to figure out how to do the rest? This is all new to me.

Comment: ya, make it 11x11. then instead of sum write this

Comment: numbers[10][i] +=numbers[j][i]; //for column

Comment: numbers[i][10] +=numbers[i][j]; //for row.  sorry, for posting so many times, every time i press an enter it becomes a new comment lol

Comment: I completely understand lol. Okay, I'm going to try that! Thanks :)

Comment: and of course where i made sum =0, make this row/column to 0...else you would get wrong values.

Comment: Okay, next question, how do I tell it to store the sum of the column at the bottom of the column? I guess I am so confused here because there are 10 different sums that'll be at the bottom and I don't understand how I'm telling the program to just put the sum of that column at the bottom of that one. This is really confusing for me.

Comment: Wait! Is that what the numbers[i][10] and numbers[10][i] are doing? Telling it where to put the sum?? Sorry for all the questions everyone. I just want to make sure I not only get the answers but that I understand them and can use what I learn for other projects.

Comment: Last question! How do I print everything. The array with the sums!

Comment: I have the most updated code posted. I can't figure out how to print it correctly. I found out that cout << number[11][11] << endl; did not work! I'm not sure what to do at all. I don't honestly have the slightest idea.

Answer (score 0):

The term *summing* means to add up numbers.  Summing the rows means to add all the numbers in the row.

```
// Pick a row to sum
const unsigned int row_to_sum = 3;

// Declare and initialize a summation variable.
float sum = 0.0f;

// Add all the columns in the given row.
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < COLS; ++i)
{
  sum += numbers[row_to_sum][i];
}
```

To sum up the a column, keep the column index constant and iterate the rows.

```
const unsigned int column_to_sum = 8;
sum = 0.0f;
for (unsigned int j = 0; j < ROWS; ++j)
{
  sum += numbers[j][column_to_sum];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have now:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Kaitlin Stevers" << endl;
    cout << "Exercise 9A - Arrays" << endl;
    cout << "October 31, 2016" <<endl;

    const int ROWS = 10;  
    const int COLS = 10;
    float numbers[11][11];
    float row, column;


    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("Ex9data.txt");

    for(int countRows = 0; countRows < ROWS; countRows++)
    {
        for(int countColumns = 0; countColumns < COLS; countColumns++)
        {
            inputFile >> numbers[countRows][countColumns];
        }
    }

    inputFile.close();

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        column = 0;
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            numbers[10][i] +=numbers[j][i];
        }
        //do the printing here & storing... column based sum here.
    }
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        row = 0;
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
        numbers[i][10] +=numbers[i][i];
        }
        //do the printing here & storing... row based sum here.
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Do you read 11 rows/column from a file? If not change `ROWS`/`COLS` back to 10 but don't change `float numbers[11][11];` as last 11 (index of 10) row/column is for result. Now you need to initialize your 11 row/column with 0 (it's important) like `numbers[10][i]=0;` just before inner loop (for). Also modify your question (edit) and don't post new answers. To refer someone in comment use @ for ex. @Logman if you want to refer to my comment.

Comment: Also `int countRows = -1; while(++countRows < ROWS)` is a little bit weird. Try this instead "for(int countRows = 0; countRows < ROWS; countRows++)`

Comment: Thank you for all this help! I'll get back to you and let you know if I need more help. :)

Comment: Will do that too! Thanks again.

Comment: int countRows = -1;
    int countCols = -1;    I keep forgetting enter submits the comment.

Comment: remove `int countRows = -1;` and `while...` swap to `for(int countRows = 0; countRows < ROWS; countRows++)` same for `countCols`

Comment: Omg you make comments so fast ;). Also don't make chat in comments as I do now and use edit option in comment. You can also delete unnecessary comments that you written by clicking on x button.